# How to set content type with JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, sharepoint-addin

I am able to create new list items programmatically with JSOM, however I can't find the correct code to set content types on the new items.

I have tried the following two methods :

```
oListItem["ContentTypeID"] = "Employee Folder";

oListItem.set_item('ContentTypeID', 'EmployeeFolder');
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint allows us to update the content type to the list item by specifying the content type id.

**SP.ListItem.set_item('ContentTypeId','<Id of the content type>');**

Please check the below snippet to update the content type to the listitem,

```
//This is a ContentType ID for Announcement content type
var contenttypeId = '0x01040005B1FCA568800F4FB4162C7A09742E67';
var lisTitle = "TestNewList";
var listitemId = 1;
UpdateListItem(lisTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId);

function UpdateListItem(listTitle, listitemId, contenttypeId) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
oListItem = oList.getItemById(listitemId);
oListItem.set_item('ContentTypeId', contenttypeId);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.load(oListItem, 'Id', 'Title', 'ContentTypeId');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        var listsInfo = '';
        listsInfo += oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\t' + oListItem.get_item('ContentTypeId');
        console.log(listsInfo.toString());
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }));
```

}

I hope, this solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the contenttypes in the Site Collection?

*I can't post all code*

```
var web = context.get_web();
webContentTypes = web.get_contentTypes();
var contentType = new SP.ContentTypeCreationInformation();
contentType.set_group(contentTypeGroup);
contentType.set_name(contentTypeName);
contentType.set_description(contentTypeDescription);
webContentTypes.add(contentType);
context.load(webContentTypes);
context.executeQueryAsync();
```

Comment: yes they are previously created content types.  When I run the calls though, I get the error "column ContentTypeID doesn't exists"

Comment: Hi, the internal names are case sensitive, use "ContentTypeId"  instead of "ContentTypeID". And pass the Id of the contentType as a value. This will solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got it:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4e3ce7/create-site-content-type-in-sharepoint-2013-using-jsom398/

```
function createContentType() {  
if (hostWebContext != undefined && hostWebContext != null) {  
    var hostWeb = hostWebContext.get_web();  
    var contentTypeCollection = hostWeb.get_contentTypes();  
    //Get Document Content type by its Id. We will use Document Content Type as Base Content Type  
    //to create a new Content Type.  
    //Refer article for Ids of other Content Types.  
    var contentType = contentTypeCollection.getById("0x0101");  
    //Creating new Content Type  
    var newContentType = new SP.ContentTypeCreationInformation();  
    newContentType.set_name('Employee');  
    newContentType.set_group('Employee Details');  
    newContentType.set_description('Content Type for Employee Details.');  
    //Set Base Content Type  
    newContentType.set_parentContentType(contentType);  
    contentTypeCollection.add(newContentType);  
    context.load(contentTypeCollection);  
    context.executeQueryAsync(  
        function () {  
            alert('Content type created successfully on Host Web.');  
        },  
       function onContenttypeFailed(sender, args) {  
           alert('Content type creation failed. Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
       });  
}
```

}